# Module "M1:M1" is already part of project "P1"

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

We have **2** **sonar** projects `(P1 & P2)` running on 2 different/independent `GIT` repositories `(G1 & G2)`. Both the projects run on different branches `(P1 runs on B1 & P2 runs on B2`).

we have `2 plugins/modules` named `M1` & `M2` in both `GITs` `G1` and `G2` on different branches.

1. In sonar project `P1` we have analysis & coverage for 2 modules `(M1 & M2)`.
2. In sonar project `P2` we have ignored these 2 modules `(M1 & M2)` both from analysis and coverage. i.e., i have included them in "sonar.coverage.exclusions" and `"sonar.exclusions"`. Even then when we run sonar project `P2` we are getting error

**Error message :**

`Module "M1:M1" is already part of project "P1"`

`Module "M2:M2" is already part of project "P1"`

I am curious why this error is displayed as they are from different `GIT`repositories and different branches of them.

Kindly suggest how can i resolve this issue. thank you.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube?

Comment: it is sonar 5.6.6

Answer (score 1):

It is not very intuitive that beside project names also the module names need to be unique in sonarqube. I think there might be a difference adding exclusions and disable the sonar report for that module. exclusions might still lead to some report.

So I would [disable the sonar report](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis) for these to modules via the skip property:

```
<sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
```

in the pom files of the two modules you don't want to have reported again.

that should avoid having the sonar plugin trying to create such a module in sonar. In the worst case you may need to delete an older project in sonar that already contains that module where it does not belong. Then re-create the reports.

Comment: In this specific case may be using sonar.skip=true solution would work. but this change ignores the analysis of both modules M1 & M2 for all sonar projects running on this repository. do we have any complete solution from the sonar side rather than maven

Comment: I am not aware of some sonar feature to take something like this apart on the sonar side. So maybe. If I may ask: why is there a copy of the plugins in both git repositories? Why are those not an own module / project and used as a dependency in both projects that use them?

Comment: there are few plugins which are used across the projects and this is way ahead to plugin unification/reuse rather than having multiple copies. we would work on git-submodules and am sure this issue will pop up again :). i am still investigating and once i have a solution i would share. thanks a lot for you time and support